# VBA cell referencing and random numbers

Tags: vba, excel, random, excel-2007, generator

I was having a play around with excel 2007 VBA and was hoping to create a Macro that generates a random number, then outputs a string based on the number generated. For example,

Number           String
1                    A
2                    B
3                    C 
4                    D

If the random number is 4, the output would be D.

I have a table of a similar nature in my Excel worksheet.

So far I have not had much success at doing this, any thoughts?

Comment: What's the full spec? Generate A - Z with equal probability?

Comment: Oh and now the spec moves. Sometimes I wonder why I bother.

Comment: And now the spec has moved back. A career in project management awaits you, @Gokatai

Comment: @Bathsheba I've rolled-back Op's edits as they invalidates 2 answers -yours and mine

Comment: New to forums and technology. Sorry for inconveniencing you.

Comment: I re-answered with a more general version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is to generate A - Z with equal probability then use `=CHAR(65 + RAND()*26)` directly on the worksheet.

It's always better to keep away from VBA as it makes spreadsheets more difficult to debug and since VBA works in a single thread, these days it can be a bottleneck.

Comment: +1 for the function solution but no idea why you hate VBA so much :) i can be fun and helpful

Answer (score 2):

Another way on worksheet, to deal with *any* string is to use

```
=CHOOSE(rand() * 4 + 1, "One", "Of", "Four", "Strings")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table as you say then you can use `INDEX`, e.g. if List is a named range containing a list of strings in separate cells you can use this formula to get a string at random

`=INDEX(List,1+RAND()*COUNTA(List))`